# Photo contests - How about just once a month?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, fun

I've just been reading [this question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/do-we-have-to-be-stack-overflow), and I have a suggestion for a compromise for having photo contests on this site.

I think having everyone open their own contest questions would be bad thing, for the same reasons others have given. What about instead, having just one every calendar month?

For example...
26 Aug - Question on meta, "What should September's contest theme be?"
 1 Sep - Question on main, "September's contest. Theme is xyz."
etc...

And if someone else tries opening their own questions outside of this plan, moderators step in.

Your thoughts?

Comment: The consensus on that question appears to be that it should be on an associated site, rather than in the "main" site. Perhaps this may garner more support if proposed as a sideline: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/304/additional-sidelines-to-the-site

Answer (score 4):

My thoughts are [the same as previously](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262/do-we-have-to-be-stack-overflow/267#267).  To sum up: no thanks.

I don't think limiting it to once a month really addresses what I see as the core problems of the idea:

- Dilutes the purpose of the site (answering questions).
- Muddies the distinction between acceptable and un-acceptable questions; there's this third category of "acceptable if it comes from the official channel, but not otherwise."
- They're not particularly inclusive.
- The site's structure inhibits providing useful feedback.